# Unreadable var_dump in Firebug when xdebug is enabled

Tags: php, firefox, error-handling, firebug, xdebug

Xdebug displays "var_dump" in its own way with more useful information, but in Firebug is unreadable.

I was wondering if there was a way to display the var_dump in Firebug to make it readable without disabling xdebug and also keeping the display of the var_dump made by xdebug in PHP.

Examples of var_dump displayed in Firebug:

```
$test = array('id' => '42', 'name' => 'Mao');
var_dump($test);
```

Default :

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "42"
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "Mao"
}
```

Xdebug :

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
  'id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'42'</font> <i>(length=2)</i>
  'name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Mao'</font> <i>(length=3)</i>
</pre>
```

Comment: What does 'unreadable' mean? No output at all? Messed-up output? Missing pieces? ...

Comment: Html are added to the var_dump, in Firebug it's more difficult to read the output.

Comment: Are you using FirePHP? As far as I know FirePHP is able to pretty-print PHP objects and arrays so there is no need to run them through var_dump()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can switch off Xdebug-`var_dump()`-overloading by setting `xdebug.overload_var_dump` to `false`. Then you can use `var_dump()` when you don't need the additional HTML-formatting and `xdebug_var_dump()` when you require a fully formatted debug output.

But as I wrote in my comment above, if you're using [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/), you can simply let FirePHP format the output in your Firebug console:

```
fb($variable, FirePHP::DUMP) // or
FB::dump('Key', $variable) // or
$firephp->dump('Key', $variable); // where $firephp is your FirePHP instance
```

Answer (score 9):

[Mike B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46675/mike-b)'s solution,

`ini_set('xdebug.overload_var_dump', 0);`

didn't work with my install.

But i can do this to supress the html :

`ini_set( 'html_errors' , 0 );`

Answer (score 6):

Setting `xdebug.overload_var_dump="0"` in *php.ini* solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 4):

`ini_set('xdebug.overload_var_dump', 0);` doesn't work here either. `ini_set( 'html_errors' , 0 );` does work but it can be very slow sometimes.

As a simple workaround you might use this:

```
echo var_export($this);
```

Which is just 7 keypresses more than the normal var_dump.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using wampserver 3.2.6, edited `php.ini` to:

```
xdebug.overload_var_dump=off
```

did nothing for me. But this one worked:

```
xdebug.mode=off
```

Now have outputs with no formating

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for some time after using Wampserver, you left-click on the Wampserver icon, then:

**PHP** -> **PHP settings** -> **xdebug.mode** -> **off**

Disable xdebug.mode according to the picture
[image]