# PHP webservice request and response

Tags: php, web-services

I'm using `PHP 5.3`, and trying to develop a simple web service that gets some parameters with POST method and has a response.

```
function start(){
    getAndValidateParams();

    global $response;
    echo json_encode($response);
}

function getAndValidateParams(){
    // token (mandatory)
    if(isset($_POST[PARAM_TOKEN])){
        echo 'got your token';
    }else{
        $response[ERROR_CODE] = ERR2_INVALID_TOKEN;
        $response[DESCRIPTION] = CODE2_DESC;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test that with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en):
[image]

**The problems:**
1. About the Xdebug HTML I saw the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465645/unreadable-var-dump-in-firebug-when-xdebug-is-enabled), If I turn the var_dump off, will it disable usage of `var_dump()` inside my php code? (I want to be able use it for debugging but not seeing that in the response).

2.Also I have a problem to pass the parameter 'token', I don't see it in `getAndValidateParams()`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your function to just get insight in this and for tesing you can use also there is Advanced REST client in chrome similar to postMAN that you are using --
use the below lines to debug this  --

```
function start(){
        $response = getAndValidateParams();
        return json_encode($response);
    }
```

// calling function ends here

```
// statrt another function that is being called 

function getAndValidateParams(){
    // token (mandatory)
    // print_r($_POST);die;  // just for debug purpose
    if(isset($_POST[PARAM_TOKEN])){
       $response[ERROR_CODE] = 0; 
       $response[DESCRIPTION] = "Success";
       $response[DEtail] = $yourdetailarr; // array of data that you want to retuen

    }else{
        $response[ERROR_CODE] = ERR2_INVALID_TOKEN;
        $response[DESCRIPTION] = CODE2_DESC;
    }
  return $response;
}
/// ends here
```

check the response here by calling start function .